# Is there a way to embed the encoding of an image into HTML?

Tags: html

Suppose I have to deliver an HTML file and I can't host the images externally and I also can't reference a local file. Is there some way I can embed the information of the image in the HTML file itself? Let me know if I need to explain my question better.

Comment: This isn't `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior,..`, it is a question about whether a specific capability exists for HTML. It's also a very reasonable question that many junior and mid-level HTML developers don't know the answer to.

Comment: I agree it's a duplicate though. Didn't see that one mentioned under Related before answering.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a [data URI](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/).

> Did you know that you don't have to link to an external image file when using an <img> element in HTML, or declaring a background-image in CSS? You can embed the image data directly into the document with data URIs.

The link also recommends an online tool to generate a data URI from an image. There are many such tools a google search away.